# Derivation after substitution not working

Tags: output-formatting, replacement

I have a code that will output an expression in form of a functions like this

```
(Λ[θ]^3 Ω[θ] - 4 (3 Derivative[1][Λ][θ] Derivative[1][Ω][θ] + Ω[θ] ( Λ′′)[θ]) - 
 4 Λ[θ] (Ω[θ] + 3 (Ω′′)[θ]))/(4 G J Λ[θ] Ω[θ]^3)
```

Now, I have functions $\Lambda(\theta)$ and $\Omega(\theta)$, that I'd like to replace with some values of theta. I tried with `->` and `:>` and none of the replacement rules will differentiate my replacement. I can differentiate the variables separately, and then specify replacement rule `Λ'[θ] -> value(θ)`, and then use `/. Derivative[1][Λ][θ]-> value[θ]`, but that seems kinda redundant.

Why isn't *Mathematica* doing it on it's own, recognising that it is the same expression, and just evaluating the derivative? This way *Mathematica* is treating differentiated lambdas or omegas as something not connected to original lambda and omega.

Why is this so, and can it be circumvented?

Comment: If you can't install the script don't use Greek letters ... it isn't that hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly what you try to do... Assume the following simple example where you have derivatives

```
expr=Expand[(D[f[x],{x,2}]+f[x])^3]
(* f[x]^3+3 f[x]^2 f''[x]+3 f[x] f''[x]^2+f''[x]^3 *)
```

The problem you are facing is that you want to apply a rule like

```
f[x_] :> Cos[x]*Sin[x]
```

This will not work on the derivatives because there `FullForm` does not match the lhs of the rule. What you probably want is to

1. replace the head `f` with your function
2. replace all `x` with the value

Therefore, if you know your function `f[x]` is now `Cos[x]*Sin[x]` you can do

```
expr /. f -> (Sin[#]*Cos[#] &)

(* -27 Cos[x]^3 Sin[x]^3 *)
```

and then you replace the value for `x`

```
% /. x->Pi
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: This one `expr /. f -> (Sin[#]*Cos[#] &)` is what I needed! Now it works :) Thank you very much :) I was wondering if it's because the `FullForm` expression for each one isn't the same and that is making an issue, and I guess it's true. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, when you replace something, you should always look at the `FullForm` when something doesn't work as you like it.

Comment: I'll have that in mind in the future :) Thanks